# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features':

Tags: visual-studio, feature-receiver, assembly-references

I am trying to deploy a SharePoint solution on my local machine.But it is giving me the following error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Failed to load
>   receiver assembly "ABC.UI, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f1756633fddf9bdd" for feature "ABC.UI_ABC.UI Feature"
>   (ID: e6694baa-bbf0-44b9-af17-6138e0a9ceb1).:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'ABC.UI, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f1756633fddf9bdd' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'ABC.UI,
>   Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f1756633fddf9bdd'
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName,
>   String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject()
>   WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> ```
>                             0              0              ABC.UI
> ```

Please help.

Comment: could you please share what steps you following, powershell script or GUI?

Comment: I am deploying it through visual studio

Comment: Changing project's strong key assembly works for me. Thanks damodar.. :)

Answer (score 2):

changing out the project’s strong key assembly worked in this particular case. If you haven’t had to change this before, it is under the properties of the project -> Signing. Under ‘Choose a strong name key file’, select New. The password is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure all latest changes are picked up, please follow steps given below:

1. Right-click the project and Retract
2. Verify the feature is gone from the filesystem, the DLLs are no longer in the GAC, etc.
3. In Visual Studio’s Solution Explorer window, click Show all files
4. Control-click bin, obj, pkj, pkjobj
5. Delete and confirm delete
6. Right-click the project and Build
7. Right-click the project and Package

Let me know if it works. If not, verify following:

1. Verifying that DLL is really part of the solution  package.?
2. Verifying that when the solution gets deployed via STSADM that the DLL is really getting put in the GAC (or BIN)?
3. Verifying that the assembly  reference that gets added  to the Feature manifest is really the signiture of the assembly in your solution?
4. Check your WSP to make sure the assembly is being deployed to the GAC and not the Web Application bin directory.  Timer Jobs must be deployed to the GAC.